# how can I access json data from another url inside a html page

Tags: php, jquery, json

here is my php code which would return json datatype

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM POST";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$sJSON = rJSONData($sql,$result);
echo $sJSON;


function rJSONData($sql,$result){
    $sJSON=array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $sRow["id"]=$row["ID"];
        $sRow["fn"]=$row["posts"];
        $sRow["ln"]=$row["UsrNM"];
        $strJSON[] = $sRow;
    }
    echo json_encode($strJSON);
}
```

this code would return

```
 [{"id":"1","fn":"hi there","ln":"karan7303"},
 {"id":"2","fn":"Shshhsev","ln":"karan7303"},
 {"id":"3","fn":"karan is awesome","ln":"karan7303"},
 {"id":"4","fn":"1","ln":"karan7303"},
 {"id":"5","fn":"asdasdas","ln":"karan7303"}]
```

But how can I access this data in html, that is, I want particular data at particular position for example i want to show 'fn' in my div and 'ln' in another div with another id

Before trying anything else I tried this

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
  url: 'exm1.php', 
  type: 'get', 
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);          
  }
});
```

but it shows that data is undefined I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Swap `$.ajaxSetup` for `$.ajax`. Also, your `rJSONData` function doesn't return anything. I would change `echo json_encode($strJSON)` to `return json_encode($strJSON)`

Comment: tried it didnt work

Comment: Use `$.ajax` function instead of `$.ajaxSetup`. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356693/how-to-keep-running-php-part-of-index-php-automatically/43357764#43357764

Comment: @SahilVerma sorry, I added more to my comment above

Comment: @Phil  tried it still doesnt work and I dont think that it was the problem because php file was returning json data anyway

Comment: Presumably `rJSONData()` is supposed to return something?

Answer (score 0):

What you've got should *kind-of* work if you swapped `$.ajaxSetup` (which is a global configuration method) with `$.ajax`. There are some significant improvements you could make though.

For example, your PHP does some odd things around the value returned by `rJSONData`. Here's some fixes

```
function rJSONData($result) {
    $sJSON = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $sJSON[] = array(
            'id' => $row['ID'],
            'fn' => $row['posts'],
            'ln' => $row['UsrNM']
        );
    }
    return json_encode($sJSON);
}
```

and when you call it

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo rJSONData($result);
exit;
```

Also make sure you have not output **any other data** via `echo` / `print` or HTML, eg `<html>`, etc

---

In your JavaScript, you can simplify your code greatly by using

```
$.getJSON('exm1.php', function(data) {
  console.info(data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

Comment: Its giving parse error
parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at m.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Pc (jquery.min.js:4)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)
(anonymous) @ exm.php:35
j @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
x @ jquery.min.js:4
b @ jquery.min.js:4

Comment: Also I could not use your rJSONData function because it was giving error on sJSON=[]; line
So i used mine rJSONData function the previous one

Comment: That worked I found out error was in my php where I used <html> at the beginning and at </html>

Comment: @SahilVerma sounds like you're running with a *very* old version of PHP if it doesn't support array literals. I've updated my answer to use the older syntax

Comment: Actually I am new to all this JSON Ajax PHP stuff So dont really know about the new and old things

Answer (score -1):

Use `$.ajax` instead of `$.ajaxSetup` function.

Here is a detailed answer from another SO post [how to keep running php part of index.php automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356693/how-to-keep-running-php-part-of-index-php-automatically/43357764#43357764)

```
<script>

$.ajax({
    // name of file to call
    url: 'fetch_latlon.php',

    // method used to call server-side code, this could be GET or POST
    type: 'GET'

    // Optional - parameters to pass to server-side code
    data: {
        key1: 'value1',
        key2: 'value2',
        key3: 'value3'
    },

   // return type of response from server-side code
   dataType: "json"

    // executes when AJAX call succeeds
    success: function(data) {
        // fetch lat/lon
        var lat = data.lat;
        var lon = data.lon;

        // show lat/lon in HTML
        $('#lat').text(lat);
        $('#lon').text(lon);
    },

    // executes when AJAX call fails
    error: function() {
        // TODO: do error handling here
        console.log('An error has occurred while fetching lat/lon.');
    }
});


</script>
```

Comment: In my case it is showing An error has occurred while fetching lat/lon. this  error because I copied that console.log line

Comment: have you changed appropriate parts of the code to match yours like `url` and `data`?

Comment: Yeah I did 
I actually only copied the error statement to make sure if its giving error or not

Comment: visit your `PHP` file in browser if it works and echo your `JSON`?

Comment: marked my answer as correct for guidance of others with similar question